# MySQL query help... checking true or false?

Tags: mysql, sql, boolean

Okay, I have a customer table

[image: in the screen shot, you can see the columns]

and what I want to do is if the customer's gender is Male, the I want to concat his name with Mr.  else if it is Female, the it should be concated with Ms. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it

```
SELECT CONCAT(CASE gender 
                WHEN 'Male' THEN 'Mr. ' 
                WHEN 'Female' THEN 'Ms. ' 
              END,  `fname`,  ' ', `lname`) AS `name` 
  FROM customer
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/704fc/1)

Output

```
|           NAME |
------------------
|   Mr. Jhon Doe |
| Ms. Helen Ross |
```

You might use `CASE gender WHEN 'Male' THEN 'Mr. ' ELSE 'Ms. '` but the problem with that is if your gender column is nullable then you'll get Ms. for all records where gender is unknown (or customer didn't want to disclose it)

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90539/4) for that

Answer (score 3):

you can use `inline IF` statement,

```
SELECT  IF(gender = 'Male', CONCAT('Mr. ', fname),CONCAT('Ms. ', fname)) Name
FROM    customer
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d053b/1)

you can also use `CASE` which other RDBMS supports

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN gender = 'Male'
            THEN CONCAT('Mr. ', fname)
            ELSE CONCAT('Ms. ', fname)
        END Name
FROM    customer
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d053b/3)